# SQL How to update two fields using CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: postgresql, case

I hope the title explains it all but I will still try and explain what I am trying to achieve. So I have a table called **users**, I need to check if the users have the following statements **true**,

- enabled
- lastaccess < (EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (86400*200))*1000

If users have above values **true** then change their enabled status to **false**. At the same time, I need to update **disabledTime** field in table with current time.

I've written the following SQL which is able to set **enabled = false** for the users but not sure how I can set **disabledTime** field.

```
UPDATE users
SET
   enabled = CASE
   WHEN
       enabled = true
       AND lastaccess != 0
       AND lastaccess < (EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (86400*200))*1000
   THEN false
   ELSE enabled
END
```

The above SQL sets user's enabled status as **false** but **disabledTime** field remains empty.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy same condition for `disabledTime` column

```
UPDATE users SET
enabled = CASE
WHEN
    enabled = true
    AND lastaccess != 0
    AND lastaccess < (EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (86400*200))*1000
THEN false
ELSE enabled
END,
disabledTime = 
CASE
WHEN
    enabled = true
    AND lastaccess != 0
    AND lastaccess < (EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (86400*200))*1000
THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ELSE disabledTime
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I thought of the same, just wondering, wouldn't the first CASE already set value of enabled to false before second CASE would check it or does it run in a single go?

Comment: @rac3b3nn0n - Both CASE's would "see" same value, so if enabled is `true`, then it  will `true` for first and for second CASE too

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out ... however is there a way of eliminating code duplication! Any other way this could be done without repeating the same code.

Comment: @rac3b3nn0n - One another way might be use trigger, after `enabled` becomes false, update `disabledTime` to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but I prefer this way, rather than trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Oto Shavadze